# How do I restart ssh or sshd on Ubuntu?

Tags: ubuntu, ssh

I want to restart ssh or sshd but I get this error:

```
qqqq@Matrix-Server:/$ sudo /etc/init.d/ssh stop
sudo: /etc/init.d/ssh: command not found
qqqq@Matrix-Server:/$
```

Do I need to install ssh or sshd or does it come with Ubuntu?

Answer (score 12):

Install openssh-server

```
sudo apt-get install openssh-server
```

Comment: After you install openssh-server, you may need to run `sudo initctl reload-configuration` before you can `sudo service ssh start`. I think this is a bug in recent versions of ubuntu (12.10,13.04).

Answer (score 6):

The **sshd** is the ssh server deamon. So if you want to connect to a machine via ssh you need to install a ssh server on your target machine, e.g. using

```
sudo apt-get install openssh-server
```

The command **ssh** is what you use to actually connect to a machine running an ssh server. You need ssh installed on the machine that you want to ssh from.

```
sudo apt-get install ssh
```

But ssh will probably already be installed if you use any decent version of Ubuntu.

---

Now about **restarting**. What do you want to restart? If you want to restart the ssh server on the other machine (e.g. if you changed the config) use

```
sudo /etc/init.d/ssh restart
```

Yes it is called *ssh* although the process is called *sshd* which might be confusing.

Answer (score 3):

There's an option in Ubuntu installing procedure to automatically install SSH server, if have not choosen it you need to install the package. The complete Ubuntu SSH package includes both server daemon and client.
To install it

```
sudo apt-get install ssh
```

Answer (score 1):

Often the service is named after the daemon. Try `/etc/init.d/sshd` instead.

Comment: i had to install openssh. I thought it comes with ubuntu , its strange

Comment: No, Ubuntu uses /etc/init.d/ssh. The default install comes with the openssh client, but not the openssh server.

Comment: even ssh was also not present in init.d directory . when i installed openssh then it came in that directory